# Discord bot python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I am coding a discord bot for my special interest can I have some help, please? The code format is this:

````
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)```

How do I make this work?
````

Comment: What exact problem are you having?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That looks like it should run fine. Do you have the .env file? We can’t help you unless you tell us what is wrong with it.

Comment: Saying client.run is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest, that you defined client wrong. Try:

```
from discord.ext import commands

//*Your dotenv stuff here*

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="Your prefix here")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I hope it works, if not, feel free to correct me.

Comment: still saying, client.run isn't defined.

Comment: What exactly is the error code? Maybe it's some of the dotenv stuff that's either deprecated or false.

Comment: You can follow a full guide here: https://pythonhowtoprogram.com/how-to-build-a-discord-bot-using-python/